# For loop through a function an DataFrame Python

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, for-loop, outliers

I write a function to remove outliers from each column in a table:( i attached a photo of the table)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a57B.png)

The function to remove the outliers is:

```
def remove_outliers(df_in, col):

    q1 = df_in[col].quantile(0.25)
    q3 = df_in[col].quantile(0.75)
    iqr = q3-q1
    lower_bound = q1-1.5*iqr
    upper_bound = q3+1.5*iqr
    df_out = df_in.loc[(df_in[col] > lower_bound) & (df_in[col] < upper_bound)]
    return df_out
```

Now i would like to make a "for loop" or any other loop, that the code run through each column of the table an do the function of removing the outliers and get a new table without outliers.

Could someone help me?

Thanks

Muhrez

Comment: you are looking for [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed use a for loop if you want, looping over the columns in the dataframe.

If your dataframe is called df you can do this:

```
for column in df.columns:
    df = remove_outliers(df, column)
```

A word of warning though, you will remove any row that has any column labeled an outlier doing this and overwrite your original dataframe :)